# Android emulator taking forever to load (OS X)

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator

I've got a MacbookPro running Intel core i5 with OS X Yosemite. So far its been over 20 minutes, and it still shows the Android loading screen. I installed the HAXM extension and confirm it is loaded:

```
➜  ~  kextstat | grep intel
147    0 0xffffff7f82bd4000 0x14000    0x14000    com.intel.kext.intelhaxm     (1.1.1) <7 5 4 3 1>
```

Here is the `avd` profile I am using:

[image]

Comment: Did you try [Why is the android emulator so slow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator?rq=1) I would try to save a state of it and disable gradle updates to speed it up slightly but in the end I just hooked it up to a real android device because it's almost instantaneous.

Comment: Don't have an android device.

Comment: [Sorry to hear that](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-m5HCfqAJOyw/UOTpSRN246I/AAAAAAAAANI/P_EuJjbQA0Q/s400/download10.gif) It took me 15 minutes for my emmy to load on W7 quad i7. Most people on the thread could at best cut it into a few minutes, so it will pay for itself if you're not broke.